Series of teen/children's books about stories from the historical religions of different countries, 80s or before
I'm looking for a great series of books I read in the mid- to late 80s, in the UK.
They were approximately A4 sized, hardback, about an inch thick, with colourful painted or drawn dust covers (the Greek one was orange-tinted or predominantly orange, the Roman was red, and maybe the Egyptian was yellow and the Norse green, I think). The cover illustration covered all of the front page with no border, not sure if it also covered the back page or not.
They told the stories of the different gods/pantheons of the countries, ie the Greek gods, Roman gods, etc., and the related myths (eg the Medusa, Cyclops). They told them in a fun and exciting way for 10+ year olds, probably but not definitely with drawings, as a series of chapters or short stories almost like a history (eg the Greek one talked about the Titans, then the coming of Zeus, then Zeus's family, then the stories of all the gods, etc.).
Does anyone know what they might have been?

There is World Mythology series by Peter Bedrick Books / Eurobook which includes:

Gods, Men and Monsters from the Greek Myths by Michael Gibson
Heroes, Gods & Emperors from Roman Mythology by Kerry Usher
Gods and Pharaohs from Egyptian Mythology by Geraldine Harris
Gods and Heroes from Viking Mythology by Brian Branston


That's incredible, Ayshe! I don't know how you did it, but you've made my day! Thank you so much, you've just helped me find a much-loved part of my childhood.
I guess I remembered the Roman one wrong, but I recognised the others the moment I saw the image.

@JamesCarlyle-Clarke great! I found it using the amazon.co.uk advanced search.
